# how to upload more than 2mb file using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying uploading a file which is more than 2mb even after setting maximum size in controller but still the file is not getting uploaded.please help to find the solution for this problem.

Below is my code:

**Controller**

```
    $config['upload_path'] = './abc/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = '*';
    $config['max_filename'] = '255';
    $config['encrypt_name'] = FALSE;
    $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
    //$config['max_size'] = '102400'; //100 MB
    $config['max_size']             = '25600';
    $config['max_width']            = '0';
    $config['max_height']           = '0';
    $config['file_name']=$newfilename;
```

Comment: You also have increase max upload size in php.ini

Comment: `php.ini` is PHP's own configuration file, not for codeigniter - see answer below.

Comment: I think your path should be  `$config['upload_path'] = './abc/';`

Answer (score 4):

The size limitation is imposed by your PHP configuration also; therefore you need to update `php.ini` and update two settings `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize`.

The `php.ini` is not found on codeigniter, rather the PHP installation on your server. Read more about it here: http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php

Say you want to allow a max upload file size of 256mb, this is what you should have on the `php.ini`:

```
post_max_size=256M
upload_max_filesize=256M
```

Once you made the change to `php.ini`, you have to restart the apache or php-fpm - depending on what you are using.

If you are on a shared hosting environment, you may not get direct access to the `php.ini` file, but your hosting provider may give you limited access to modify php configuration via their hosting control panel such as cPanel or Plesk etc...

If you developing locally, and say you are on windows using XAMPP for example; the `php.ini` file is usually found here: `C:\xampp\php\php.ini` (depends on where you've installed xampp). On linux, the php.ini configuration tends to be somewhere like `/etc/php.ini` (not always guranteed).

You could always create a file on your server called `phpinfo.php` with this script: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and visit it, e.g. http://localhost/phpinfo.php and it will show you the location the loaded `php.ini` file as well as the current setting values of `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize`.

Comment: i created php.ini file in my root directory n wrote the above code but its not working

Comment: i read your answer....even by using phpinfo(); function i got the path of the php.ini file but when i opened that folder there was no such file.And i am developing it on shared hosting environment not locally .

Answer (score 2):

You can change your .htaccess file in the root folder of your CI project. This is good for shared hosting where you may not change php.ini):

```
## I need more memory (50M) to upload large image
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_value memory_limit 256M
  php_value post_max_size 50M
  php_value upload_max_filesize 50M
</IfModule>
```

in Codeigniter you set filesize preferences in your config.php file: see [docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html#preferences)

Comment: i tried writing above code in my .htaccess then i am getting error @Vickel