# Can't upload file more than 2 MB in codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

i can't upload file more than 2 MB in codeigniter 4. How to increase the limit size in codeingiter 4?

```
public function store()
    {

        helper('text');

        $data = $this->request->getPost();
        if($data['type'] === 'structure and written expression'){
            $file = $this->request->getFile('story');
            $path = WRITEPATH.'uploads';
            $filename = $file->getRandomName();
            $file->move($path, $filename);
            $data = [
                'type' => $data['type'],
                'text_question' => $filename
            ];

        }
        $story = new StoryModel;
        $id = $story->insert($data);

        if($story->errors())
        {
            return $this->fail($story->errors());
        }

        if($id === false)
        {
            return $this->failServerError("Server Error");
        }

        $data=null;

        return $this->respondCreated(['status' => 'created success', 'id'=>$id]);
    }
```

this is my create function in controller

Comment: Add code that you have tried so far.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47053613/how-to-upload-more-than-2mb-file-using-codeigniter

Comment: I finding, it was my PHP config, i change my max_upload 2M to more than 2 MB in php. ini, thx everyone

Answer (score 0):

I agree what in link with Marged shared, and you can add more code to compress image with:

`$config['quality']='50%';`

Comment: how if i upload the music file? Can i compress it?